add ID of input element into newly created form
I am using convForm - https://github.com/eduardotkoller/convForm
However on my form I have input elements with the ID values set.
When the script is called it creates a new form based on the old elements but it won't add in the id value of the original select options.
In the convform.min.js file there is this :
This relates to the select options
if (answers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    var option = $('<div class="option" id="'+ this.wrapper.(find(this.answers[i].getAttribute('id'))) +'">' + answers[i].text + "</div>").data("answer", answers[i]).click(function(event) {
                        this.current.input.selected = $(event.target).data("answer").value, this.wrapper.find(this.parameters.inputIdHashTagName).removeClass("error"), this.wrapper.find(this.parameters.inputIdHashTagName).val(""), this.answerWith($(event.target).data("answer").text, $(event.target).data("answer")), this.wrapper.find("div.options div.option").remove()
                    }.bind(this));

This is the part of the code I tried to edit and add in the
id="'+ this.wrapper.(find(this.answers[i].getAttribute('id'))) +'"

However it just does nothing.
I'm not sure if I'm adding the path correctly.
Here is my form :
<div id="chat2" class="conv-form-wrapper">
        <form method="post" class="hidden" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                    <select data-conv-question="Hi, what is your query regarding ?" name="querytype">
                    <option value="Quote">Quote</option>
                    <option value="Order Query">Order Query</option>
                    <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
                    </select>
                    <textarea data-callback="storeState" type="text" data-conv-question="Brilliant, how can we help you today ?" name="initialQ"></textarea>
                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Great ! Can I please take your full name ?" name="name">
                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="What is your phone number in case we get disconnected ?" name="phone">
                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Awesome, and what is your email address ?" name="email">
                    <input type="text" data-conv-question="Great, thanks {name}:0! Lets get you connected to us.." data-no-answer="true">
                    <select data-conv-question="Choose a platform to speak to someone LIVE" id="platform" name="platform">
                                    <option value="whatsapp" id"whatsapp">&nbsp;</option>
                                    <option value="messenger" id="messenger">&nbsp;</option>
                    </select>
                  </form>

If anyone could have a look and guide me that would be appreciated
